# Translation of "you cut I choose"

Tags: translation

I'm trying to give a presentation to my Chinese class on fair division procedures, and I want to describe the simple method of "you cut I choose". I think a literal translation would be something like 你分为我选择, but I wonder if there's a colloquial way to say this or some relevant chengyu.

Comment: Why do you use "为"？

Comment: It was in my dictionary, @wuyefeibao.

Comment: that is a separate question. If you say "cut it into two pieces" you can say "分为两块", but "you cut" can only be "你切".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you simply name it "你切我选".

Other names to this method is "我切你选", "分割与选择"(divide and choose), "切蛋糕问题"(cake-cutting problem)

Answer (score 2):

In additional to wuyefeibao's suggestion, "分者後取" or "分者後拿" is also okay.

"分者" == the one who cuts

"後取/拿" => takes the remaining piece after the other person

Answer (score 1):

In Cantonese, I would explain this way

爲公平起見，你切餅，我揀先，又或者，我切餅，你揀先。